# How to convert String to Integer from OData-Model in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have an OData model with some Edm.String fields which represents ABAP NUMC(9) or NUMC(10). All other Edm-Types (like Int32) ends with an error.

Can I now convert these Fields to Integer in SAPUI5? The content is i.e. `0000012345`. If I use type in my binding, my text is empty. If I use it without type, the strings are output correctly.

```
new sap.m.Text({
  text: {
    path: "{statusData>AnzPdf}",
    type: new sap.ui.model.type.Integer()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `formatter` as give in [example](http://jsbin.com/qudowo/3/edit?html,js,output) to convert data from model to `Integer` format.

Comment: Why the regex? "010" will be interpreted as 10 and not 8. The octal conversion is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! I have modified answer accordingly.

Comment: Check out the modified answer!